# Cocos2d-x coordinates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, coordinate-systems

I just started with Cocos2D-x after some years using Cocos2d-iPhone/swift/spritebuilder.

What I notice is that the coordinate system in X seems not to use the POINT system common since iOS development. Ie a box of 10x10 points used to be 10x10 pixels on 1x devices, 20x20 pixels on 2x devices and so on.

So my question is, does cocos2d-x only deal with pixels? How do we address this in code - because we used to be able to put a sprite at say 50x20 and it would end up in the right spot on any device regardless of resolution. Not possible in cocos2d-x? I have 3.5.

What would be related is this document, however it says that it is outdated. Is there a newer document anywhere? I really don't find anything else. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Comment: I have been looking into this recently and was surprised what I found regarding calling getWinSize, getWinSizeInPixels, and getVisibleSize on an iPhone 5.  Part of my answer here is related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786958/using-sprite-atlases-in-a-multi-resolution-setup-in-cocos2d-x/29805409#29805409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into using different asset folders for various resolution sizes. So you might have "/sd/" for < 480 height, "/hd/" for < 800 height, and "/ipadhd/" for others.

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder(...)
```

You can also change the content scale factor yourself in the AppController.mm using:

```
// should behave as if all art is @1x device
Director::getInstance()->setContentScaleFactor(1.0);
// should behave as if all art is @2x device
Director::getInstance()->setContentScaleFactor(2.0);
// should behave as if all art is @4x 
Director::getInstance()->setContentScaleFactor(4.0);
```

This hasn't been updated yet, but still has some info:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support

Comment: Well yes the deal is to set *designResolutionSize*. Doing this would make us have a consistent "point" size, and for one device class (like iPhone 5, 5s, 5c) we would only need one set of coordinates. Now of course it still gets more difficult because iPhone 4, 6, 6 Plus, iPads, Androids etc have more/less points than said device class. The page you linked is marked as outdated, yet still seems to be the only place of information in the whole of the official Cocos2d-x community that explains what's going on. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support#designResolutionSize

Comment: Yeah, I should maybe write up something with a test project included for the programming guide, otherwise I don't think it'll be updated for a while. I know it's one of the features constantly in flux because multi-resolution + multi-density can be tricky. Android (density/resolution specific XML and folders) is done differently from iOS (@2x, @3x)

Comment: Agreed. I am working on iOS devices initially, and somehow assume I can later, for Android devices, make use of the same assets provided I use a bit different setup. :-P

Comment: The cocos2dx wiki link above seems to have gone dead.. this one is somewhat useful though: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/10/01/Cocos2d-x-Tutorial-Series-Basic-Graphics.aspx